# Memory Allocation Error when uploading large file to Rails app with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, carrierwave

I have looked at the following question but it doesn't give a satisfactory solution to my problem:

[getting my rails app to accept large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32774962/getting-my-rails-app-to-accept-large-files)

I am using Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.1 and Mongodb 3.2, Carrierwave 0.10.0 and Mongoid 5.0.2. I am able to upload relatively small files (<20mb) successfully to the database. But when I attempt to upload a large file (approximately 500mb) I get the following error in the console:

> Started GET "/invoice_collections/new" for ::1 at 2016-01-20 14:24:12 +0200
>   Processing by InvoiceCollectionsController#new as HTML
>    Rendered invoice_collections/new.html.erb within layouts/application (28.0ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 129ms (Views: 128.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>   [2016-01-20 14:25:30] **ERROR NoMemoryError: failed to allocate memory**
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httprequest.rb:254:in 'block >in body'
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httprequest.rb:479:in 'call'
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httprequest.rb:479:in >`read_body'
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httprequest.rb:255:in 'body'
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:62:in 'service'
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in >'service'
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in 'run'
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in 'block in >start_thread'

While I see this in the console I see a plain white page rather than the view I should be seeing.

Where RailsInstaller is where my Ruby and Rails installation is contained. It was downloaded here:

http://railsinstaller.org/en

I have tried minimizing memory use on my pc while trying to do this but that has not helped. I have tried reinstalling rails and ruby without success. I have tried running the app on the cloud 9 ide rather than from my machine and it has worked and my machine has more memory than the cloud 9 ide. The reason I need to use my machine for testing, however, is that there are some rather hefty operation I must perform on the uploaded files.

What is causing this error on my machine? What can I do to fix it?

**Update:**
I have tried to run the app on a pc with 32 GB of RAM. Still gives the exact same error, so I don't think it is to do with my PC's memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that the problem was with webrick. I'm not sure what exactly the problem was but I got it working using Thin instead of webrick.